# How to get directory names in php

Tags: php, scandir

how can I get all folders in a directory and make

```
if name of folder == $variable {
  code...
}
```

Can you help-me please?

Answer (score 0):

use glob package

```
elementsIncurrendDir = glob("regExpFiler*.[tT][xX][tT]")

for s in elementsIncurrendDir:
   if s== 'whatever':
      pass
```

If you want to verify that it is a folder you can use:

```
if os.path.isdir(s):
```

Comment: I don't understand the part glob("regExpFiler*.[tT][xX][tT]")...sorry

Comment: @SandroMedeiros it is a filter, in you don't want filter by name you can put just glob("*")

Comment: You are right, I didn't see php in the title. It's python.

Answer (score 0):

You can get files and folders by using [`scandir()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php) function which returns array of filenames.

Function [`array_diff()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) computes difference between two arrays and effectively removes filenames `.` and `..` from the array of filenames.

```
$directory = '/path/to/my/directory';
$scanned_directory = array_diff(scandir($directory), array('..', '.'));
```

You can then check if file is a directory using [`is_dir()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-dir.php) function and also check for name of the folder.

```
foreach ($scanned_directory as $filename) {
    if (is_dir($filename) && $filename == "folder_name") {
         // filename is directory with name folder_name
    }
}
```